# MySQL UNION Sub Select is slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have 6 tables

1. Table a_orders = 41915 rows.
2. Table a_orders_items = 77765 rows.
3. Table a_orders_items_history = 379611 rows.
4. Table b_orders = 743032 rows.
5. Table b_orders_items = 984839 rows.
6. Table b_orders_items_history = 5685609 rows.

I want to get the orders data by filtering the order date and the orders status,
So, i have query like this:

> ```
> SELECT orders_id, item_id, qty, status, order_date
> FROM (
>        (SELECT bo.orders_id AS orders_id,
>           boi.orders_items_id AS item_id, boi.order_quantity AS qty,
>           boish.status AS status, bo.import_date AS order_date
>         FROM b_orders bo
>           LEFT JOIN b_orders_items boi ON boi.orders_id = bo.orders_id
>           LEFT JOIN b_orders_items_history boih ON boih.orders_items_id = boi.orders_items_id
>         WHERE bo.partner_id IN (2,10) AND DATE(boish.status_date) >= DATE('2015-10-27')
>               AND DATE(boish.status_date) <= DATE('2016-04-26') AND boish.status = 10
>         GROUP BY boish.status_date, boish.status)
>        UNION ALL
>        (SELECT ao.orders_id AS orders_id, aoi.orders_products_id AS item_id, aoi.products_quantity AS qty,
>           opsh.status AS status, ao.date_purchased AS order_date
>         FROM a_orders ao
>           LEFT JOIN a_orders_items aoi ON aoi.orders_id = ao.orders_id
>           LEFT JOIN a_orders_items_history aoih ON aoih.orders_products_id = aoi.orders_products_id
>         WHERE DATE(aoih.status_date) >= DATE('2015-10-27') AND DATE(aoih.status_date) <= DATE('2016-04-26')
>               AND aoih.status = 10 GROUP BY aoih.status_date, aoih.status)
>      ) temp_table GROUP BY item_id, status;
> ```

It tooks 5 seconds to complete, and mysql slow query also logged.
Is there any i can do to make it faster?
I've been tried using UNION, and also to place it outside the subquery the WHERE filter, but the result was the same.

EDIT:
I will show the EXPLAIN result here:

```
      id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | extra

1|PRIMARY|<derived2>|ALL|null|null|null|null|3385|Using temporary; Using filesort
2|DERIVED|bo|ALL|PRIMARY,customer_billing_id,customer_shipping_id|null|null|null|743032|Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2|DERIVED|boi|ref|PRIMARY,Index_Orders|Index_Orders|4|bo.bo_orders_id|1|Using where
2|DERIVED|boih|ref|orders_items_id|orders_items_id|5|boi.orders_items_id|1|Using where
3|UNION|aoi|ALL|PRIMARY,orders_id|null|null|null|77765|Using temporary; Using filesort
3|UNION|ao|eq_ref|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4|aoi.orders_id|1|empty
3|UNION|aoih|ref|orders_products_id|orders_products_id|5|aoi.orders_products_id|1|Using where
null|UNION RESULT|<union2,3>|ALL|null|null|null|null|null|empty
```

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: 1) Pls describe what your query is supposed to do. Understanding what you would like to achive would enable us to suggest alternative solutions. 2) Pls add the results of explain for your current query. 3) Pls provide list of existing indexes in the affected tables.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `LEFT JOIN b_orders_items boi ON boi.orders_id = boi.orders_id` ?

Comment: It seems to me, that you want to fetch orders from 2 order table & there is no relation between the two order table.Is it correct? If yes, then implement indexing properly.

Comment: @tilz sorry, i've updated the query. That is mistype.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to explain your query, that will give you information about index usage of your queries... You can it in MySQL documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html